# Reformat german datestring to sql date in php

Tags: php, parsing, date, format

I'm trying to parse a german string to a date that I can reformat for a sql database.

The string I've got looks like: `15. Mai 2015`, which is basically this format: `d. F Y`.
How can I reformat it to a date in this format: `Y-m-d` using PHP? I've tried `strtotime()` with the correct locale but it wasn't successful.

### Edit 1:

I've tried this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
date_format(
    date_create_from_format("d. F Y", $str),
    'Y-m-d'
);
```

and this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
strftime("%Y-%m-%d", strtotime($str))
```

### Edit 2:

I've solved it like suggested:

```
function parseDate($str) {
    $months = array(
        "Januar"    => "January",
        "Februar"   => "February",
        "März"      => "March",
        "April"     => "April",
        "Mai"       => "May",
        "Juni"      => "June",
        "August"    => "August",
        "September" => "September",
        "Oktober"   => "October",
        "November"  => "November",
        "Dezember"  => "December"
    );

    return strtotime(strtr($str, $months));
}
```

But isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988536/strtotime-with-different-languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to
[Converting a German date to Y-m-d does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481320/converting-a-german-date-to-y-m-d-does-not-work)

You need to replace string for month by english month name in order to use strtotime.

Comment: Yeah, I see, but isn't there a more elegant way?